# Remove class from element inside bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using a bootstrap popover to show a list of available actions for a list of recipients.
Popover:

```
<ul class='list-unstyled recipients-popover'>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item' onclick='openAddContactModal()'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Add contact</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Add contact list</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item disabled' onclick='deleteContacts()'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Delete contacts</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item' onclick='openAddGroupModal()'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Create new group</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item disabled' onclick='openAddContactToGroupModal()'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Add contacts to group</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item disabled'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Remove contacts from Group</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item' onclick='openDeleteGroupModal()'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Delete Group</a></li>
```

The above is triggered by the below HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-link text-white" tabindex="0" role="button" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto" data-content=" @include('recipient.actions-popover') ">
```

Then issue is when I try to run javascript on the popover it isnt working. For example, if I try and run:

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkable', function(e) {
    console.log("testing");
    $(".popover-item").removeClass('disabled');
});
```

The disabled class does not get removed although I do see the testing console log.

Can anyone help get the above working?

Comment: where is  `checkable` in your change event?

Comment: It's on the same file as the Javascript. `<input type="checkbox" name="recipient[3]" class="checkable" contactid="3">`

Comment: your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove a class when the checkbox change, this works fine :

```js
$(".checkable").change(function() {
       $(".popover-item").removeClass('disabled');
});
```

```css
.disabled{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='list-unstyled recipients-popover'>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item' onclick='openAddContactModal()'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Add contact</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Add contact list</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item disabled' onclick='deleteContacts()'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Delete contacts</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item' onclick='openAddGroupModal()'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Create new group</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item disabled' onclick='openAddContactToGroupModal()'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Add contacts to group</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item disabled'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Remove contacts from Group</a></li>
<li><a href='#' class='popover-item' onclick='openDeleteGroupModal()'><i class='test'></i> &nbsp; Delete Group</a></li>

<label>Checkable</label> <input type="checkbox" name="recipient[3]" class="checkable" contactid="3">
```